# Bean validation succeeded but failed on jpa merge method

Tags: jpa, bean-validation

I want to persist an entity(MyEntity) with merge method. This entity have some beans validation.

```
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity {


@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "city", length = 255, nullable = false)
@NotNull
@NotEmpty(message = "{myentity.validation.size.name}")
private String city;
private String number;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "zipcode", length = 255, nullable = false)
@NotNull    
private String zipcode;
private String phoneNumber;
@Email(message = "{myentity.validation.conform.email}")
@Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "{myentity.validation.size.email}")
private String email;
private String website;
private String gpsLocation;

@ElementCollection()
@CollectionTable(name = "translation_poi", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "point_id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "locale")    
@NotEmpty
private Map<Locale, MyEntityI18n> translations = new HashMap<>();
```

}

```
 @Embeddable
public class MyEntityI18n implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "{myentity.validation.size.name}")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "comment", length = 1200)
    private String comment;
    @Column(name = "short_description", length = 1200)
    private String shortDescription;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The merge succeeded on an existing entity value but with a new entity the merge failed despite the fact that the following validation succeeded.

```
 private boolean validate(MyEntity poi) {

    boolean result = true;
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyEntity>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(poi);
    if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
        result = false;
        for (ConstraintViolation<MyEntity> constraints : constraintViolations) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String message = constraints.getPropertyPath() + " " + constraints.getMessage();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, constraints.getMessage(), message));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: failed in which way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `@Valid` to `MyEntity.translations` property. I think that your validation method hasn't take account the `MyEntityI18n.name` validation.

About merge fails, Do you have a not-null DB constraint on the `MyEntityI18n.name` field?

Good luck!

Comment: So, please, _mark the check_ as the right response. This way people can identify it better.